# Using Powershell looping through folders, create a folder with the name "test" in each

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

How can I loop through a folder, and create folder "test" in each one. And after that move the complete subfolder structure into it.

First the structure looks like this:

```
├─Folder1
│ ├─Subfolder1
│ └─Subfolder2
└─Folder2
  ├─Subfolder1
  └─Subfolder2
```

The Goal is that it looks like this:

```
├─Folder1
│ └─Test
│   ├─Subfolder1
│   └─Subfolder2
└─Folder2
  └─Test
    ├─Subfolder1
    └─Subfolder2
```

I tried different approaches. Something like this:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem U:\AsBuiltKopieScript\Kopie10StandorteCD1\* -Directory;
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
  $folder = New-Item -Type Directory -Path "U:\AsBuiltKopieScript\Kopie10StandorteCD1\#Folder.Fullname\GebäudeMast"
  Move-Item #Folder.Fullname -Destination 
}
```

But it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is when you make your destination path, try this

```
$Root="U:\AsBuiltKopieScript\Kopie10StandorteCD1"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\root" -directory | %{
$NewItem=New-Item -Path "$($_.FullName)\test" -ItemType Directory -Force
Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | where fullname -ne $NewItem.FullName | Move-Item -Destination $NewItem.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Short question, I am new to Powershell but does the % stand in as alias for the foreach command?

Comment: Yes it is, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Get-ChildItem U:\AsBuiltKopieScript\Kopie10StandorteCD1\ -Directory -recurse | % { New-Item -type directory -path "$($_.FullName)" -Name "test"}
```